# Autocomplete with force of a choice

Tags: jquery, .net, autocomplete

I want to use autocomplete (jquery or .net) with force a choice so that the user must always choose something.  There can be no possibility of entry, the user can only choose.

Does anyone know how to do this??

I want to use webservice for this purpose, because the results will be a lot, and I'll show you the first few.

I want to display text in hidden field after choosing to save the value

---

I want to use webservice for this purpose, because the results will be a lot, and I'll show you the first few

Comment: Why don't you use a `<select>`?

Comment: ugh, the edits made this _less_ readable

Comment: @Andy -- if the data is dynamic **and/or** the potential options to choose from are many, a select is actually a worse choice.

Comment: @David - there were simultaneous edits and the result was less than flattering because I didn't edit as much -- only the typos.  I've rolled it back to the intermediate edit.

Comment: @tvanfosson: but an autocomplete with "no possibility of entry" is rather contradictory, and options in a select element can be quickly found by typing which would give the (presumed) desired effect here.

Comment: @Andy -- just from a design perspective if a select has more than about 20 options it's very unwieldy.  Autocomplete -- with forced match, i.e., you can type it but it has to match an existing element -- is much preferable when you have many more potential elements, for example, all of the users in your system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing this with the jQuery UI widget is going to require a bit of extra work on your part.  I suggest that you consider using the non-UI [autocomplete](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete/autocomplete#url_or_dataoptions) plugin with the `mustMatch` option.  Note, though, that if the user has javascript turned off, this will not guarantee that the value of the input is always from your set of options.

**EDIT**:  Sample parser for the autocomplete plugin.  Expects an array of JSON objects of the form:

```
[ {
    "FirstName" : "john",
    "LastName" : "smith",
    "Email" : "john-smith@example.com"
  },
  ...
]
```

Autocomplete setup

```
$('.selector').autocomplete({
      ...
      parse: function(data) {
                var array = new Array();
                for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++)
                {
                    var datum = data[i];
                    var name = datum.FirstName + ' ' + datum.LastName;
                    var display =  name + ' (' + datum.Email + ')';
                    array[array.length] = { data: datum, value: display, result: name };
                }
                return array;
             },
      ...
})
```

Comment: if it supports the text - value items??
I want to display text in hidden field after choosing to save the value

Comment: You can basically send back any sort of data by providing a `parse` method and adding a `result` handler.  The `parse` method (added as an option) takes the data returned from the server and returns an array of objects with `data`, `value`, and `result` parameters.  I'll add a sample implementation.

Comment: sample implementation - that was great :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery [autocomplete](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-change)  widget as it supports force selection.

```
        var availableTags = [
            "ActionScript",
            "AppleScript"
        ];
        $("#tags").autocomplete({
            source: availableTags,
            change: function (event, ui) {
                if(!ui.item){
                    //http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-change -
                    // The item selected from the menu, if any. Otherwise the property is null
                    //so clear the item for force selection
                    $("#tags").val("");
                }

            }

        });
```